# numpy array passed to function doesnt change

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have tried a lot to save this problem but wasnt able to solve it unfortunatly.

I want to pass an numpy array to a function and change it there.

```
def GetDataFromDAQ(self, timestamp, msdata, signalname):
    tmptime, tmpdata = self.DAQ.return_data(signalname)
    timestamp= np.append(timestamp, tmptime)
    msdata = np.append(msdata, tmpdata)
```

thats the call for the function

```
self.ActiveMSData = MeasurementData()
self.GetDataFromDAQ(self.ActiveMSData.RawData["timestamps"], self.ActiveMSData.RawData["data"], "frequency")
```

and thats a part of the class

```
class MeasurementData():
def __init__(self):
    self.RawData = {}
    self.RawData["timestamps"] = np.empty(0)
    self.RawData["data"] = np.empty(0)
```

I debugged it with VS Code and saw that the arrays timestamp and msdata in the function get filled but the members of the Measurementclass which i passed dont get changed at all. 
What am i missing here? 
Thank you in advance for your help. 
Raphael

Comment: You forgot the return statement in the function

Comment: @wwii so every assignement changes the the memory adress of the variable. so its not the same as i passed since i just passed the adress. am i understanding this right?

Comment: @Saroten adding a return value does not change anything

Comment: Yes, the assignment in the function makes the name a variable within the function's scope.  [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) - I'll try to find some related SO Q&A's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignments in the function make the names variables within the function's scope.

If `GetDataFromDAQ` is a method/function of the same class/instance You will have to assign the new array to the instance attributes.

```
def GetDataFromDAQ(self, timestamp, msdata, signalname):
    tmptime, tmpdata = self.DAQ.return_data(signalname)
    self.RawData["timestamps"] = np.append(timestamp, tmptime)
    self.RawData["data"] = np.append(msdata, tmpdata)
```

If you want the function to be less specific, you will have to return the new data.

```
def GetDataFromDAQ(self, timestamp, msdata, signalname):
    tmptime, tmpdata = self.DAQ.return_data(signalname)
    t = np.append(timestamp, tmptime)
    d = np.append(msdata, tmpdata)
    return t,d

t = self.ActiveMSData.RawData["timestamps"]
d = self.ActiveMSData.RawData["data"]
t,d = self.GetDataFromDAQ(t,d,"frequency")
self.ActiveMSData.RawData["timestamps"],self.ActiveMSData.RawData["data"] = t,d
```

---

A complication of your original attempt is that you are creating a *brand new* object with `append` rather than modifying an existing object. If you really want to try to make the function generic you could anticipate the the largest size that your time series data might become and *initialize* the arrays to that size filling them with a value that allows you to determine where to *insert* the next series of data. Then in the function you can assign to a slice of the arrays without creating new objects. Something like this.

```
import numpy as np
rawdata = {'timestamps':np.full(10,np.nan),
           'data':np.full(10,np.nan)}

def f(t,d):
    nextt = np.argmax(np.isnan(t))
    nextd = np.argmax(np.isnan(d))
    newdata = [1,2,3]
    newtimestamps = [8,7,6]
    endt = nextt + len(newtimestamps)
    endd = nextd + len(newdata)
    t[nextt:endt] = newtimestamps
    d[nextd:endd] = newdata
    return None
    
##print(rawdata)
t = rawdata['timestamps']
d = rawdata['data']
f(t,d)
f(t,d)
print(rawdata)
```

---

From [9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) of the tutorial in the documentation-

> A special quirk of Python is that – if no global or nonlocal statement is in effect – assignments to names always go into the innermost scope. Assignments do not copy data — they just bind names to objects. The same is true for deletions: the statement del x removes the binding of x from the namespace referenced by the local scope. In fact, all operations that introduce new names use the local scope: in particular, import statements and function definitions bind the module or function name in the local scope.

The previous section. 9.1. A Word About Names and Objects, is worth reading along with [4.2. Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) in the Language Reference part of the docs.

---

Numpy does have operations that *modify in place* if the same name is given for their `out` parameter e.g. [numpy.multiply](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html#numpy.multiply)  - those operations would have worked as you intended.  Here is a toy example.

```
import numpy as np
rawdata = {'timestamps':np.ones(4),
           'data':np.ones(4) * 2}

def f(a,b):
    np.multiply(a, 5, out=a)
    np.subtract(b, 3, out=b)
    
print(rawdata)
a = rawdata['timestamps']
b = rawdata['data']
f(a,b)
print(rawdata)
```

Comment: that works. thank you very much! 
i wanted to make it differently so i can use one function for different dataarrays but i guess i have to make a function for each array or work with returnvalues then.

Comment: That section of the Tutorial mentions the global and nonlocal keywords maybe nonlocal could be made to work.